# Plot graph from within Mata

Tags: stata

Consider the following toy matrix in `mata`:

```
mata: A

            1       2
     +-----------------+
   1 |   6555     140  |
   2 |   7205     135  |
   3 |   6255     140  |
   4 |   7272     138  |
   5 |  10283     133  |
   6 |   8244     136  |
   7 |   6909     144  |
   8 |   7645     138  |
   9 |  12828     134  |
  10 |   6538     137  |
     +-----------------+
```

If I want to draw a scatter plot using this matrix, I first need to transfer it
to Stata and then also convert it to variables with the `svmat` command:

```
mata: st_matrix("A", A)

svmat A
list, separator(0)

     +-------------+
     |    A1    A2 |
     |-------------|
  1. |  6555   140 |
  2. |  7205   135 |
  3. |  6255   140 |
  4. |  7272   138 |
  5. | 10283   133 |
  6. |  8244   136 |
  7. |  6909   144 |
  8. |  7645   138 |
  9. | 12828   134 |
 10. |  6538   137 |
     +-------------+

twoway scatter A1 A2
```

Is there a way to *directly* draw the graph without leaving `mata`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can plot a `mata` matrix without first converting it to Stata variables as follows:

```
twoway scatter matamatrix(A)
```

See `help twoway_mata` for more details.

---

**Edit by @PearlySpencer:**

This can be run directly from within `mata` using the `stata()` function:

```
mata: stata("twoway scatter matamatrix(A)")
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to use the *community-contributed* `mata` function `mm_plot()`:

```
mata: mm_plot(A, "scatter")
```

This is part of the `moremata` collection of functions and must thus be downloaded  first:

```
ssc install moremata
```